# How to insert a record for each result in a mySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Hello I call mysql query select in console (or in phpmyadmin sql cmd)

```
SELECT HF, ID FROM AH WHERE HF !=0 GROUP BY HF;
```

After this I need to execute command for each returned line from previous select

```
foreach
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TOT` WHERE `ID` = @selectedID AND `Uto` = @selectedHF ) = 0 THEN    
      INSERT INTO `TOT` (`ID`, `HF`) VALUES (@selectedID, @selectedHF);
  END IF;
endforeach;
```

How can I do this "foreach" loop in mysql?

Comment: [MySQL Cursors](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Cursors would accomplish the task, but [INSERT INTO..... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) looks like it might also be able to accomplish the goal. Cursors are generally not good to use where they can be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single query, `insert . . . select`.  No need for a loop, but you do want to check non-existence:

```
INSERT INTO `TOT` (`ID`, `HF`) 
    SELECT ID, HF
    FROM AH a
    WHERE HF <> 0 AND 
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TOT WHERE TOT.ID = a.ID AND TOT.UTO = @selectedHF)
    GROUP BY HF;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for your reply. I chandeg `Uto` = HF to `Uto` = @selectedHF - will it affect somehow your query?

Comment: @peter . . . no it shouldn't.